# 也 and 还 diference not clear enough

Tags: grammar

I thouht 还 ment besides or además(in spanish)， it gives more informatión but let me give you an example

There are clear examples like when you say i play piano, he plays piano to. Here where you have two subjects doing the same thing is obvius that you use 也。

But in the next example I asked my teacher if you could use 还 instead of 也 and she said that if you use 还 it is not right or properly used. ¿is it because you are still talking about things about his studies in both sentences?. She said 还 would not be proper but would not explain clear to me.

他上课时开始不专心听讲。他的学习成绩**也**越来越差。

Saludos desde España. Málaga. Greetings from Málaga Spain.

Answer (score 2):

还 can be translated to something like "not only that" or "furthermore" in English. On the other hand, 也 means something like "and" or "also". Their literal meaning is almost exactly the same, but 还 places an additional emphasis on the object that comes afterwards.

In your example

> 他上课时开始不专心听讲。他的学习成绩也越来越差。

This roughly translates to

> He doesn't listen attentively during lessons. His results are also getting worse over time.

This places more or less equal emphasis on “不专心听讲” and “学习成绩”. On the other hand, the following version

> 他上课时开始不专心听讲。他的学习成绩还越来越差。

roughly means

> He doesn't listen attentively during lessons. Not only that, his results are getting worse over time!

So there is a greater emphasis on the 学习成绩越来越差 in the latter version with the 还 over the 也, and there's a slight difference in meaning. So although both are perfectly grammatical sentences, they do have slightly different meaning, and it depends on which meaning you want to express when choosing terms.